# How can I make a regex to filter a URL pattern so that it terminates after 8 char wildcard and then directory slash?

Tags: javascript, regex, google-tag-manager

I need to write a regex for a Google Tag Manager trigger. I want to be able to trigger the tag on a particular URL pattern: `pre-store/cvsfds/`

and not pick up another URL which is reserved for another event: `pre-store/cvsfds/ekyc_2/ekyc_2/`

I am writing the following expression `pre-store\/(.+?\/)` but it still matches the other URL pattern with the two more levels of subdirectory. I try to use the `$` symbol to terminate at the second slash (after the 8 digit code) but it doesn't appear to be working for me https://regex101.com/r/U3WBB1/1

How can I make the regex just target `pre-store/cvsfds/` only?

Comment: You need a negated character class, `pre-store\/([^\/]+\/)$`. `.+?` matches as few as possible, but *as many as necessary to find a match*.

Comment: Did it work as expected?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew did you write that regex correctly? I tried to put it into regex101 https://regex101.com/r/7p4XFN/1 but it does not appear to match anything.

Comment: You are not using my pattern, the right demo is https://regex101.com/r/7p4XFN/2

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks for the correction. I checked this out on regex101 and it all tests out right but for some strange reason, GTM is still rejecting it but this tool has a very "particular" take on ECMAScript so I think I need to work on it some more.

Comment: In Google Tag Manager, there can be other restrictions for the pattern. Try making it match the whole string with `.*pre-store/([^/]+/)$`. Check if you have the `Full Matches Only` option enabled.

Answer (score 0):

For regex, you may use `/[\/]*[^\/]+[\/]([^\/]+)/` or you may use split('/') as well.

```js
//regex
let str = 'pre-store/cvsfds/ekyc_2/ekyc_2/';
let matches = str.match(/[\/]*[^\/]+[\/]([^\/]+)/);
document.write(`regex method:<br> ${matches[0]}/`);

//split method
let splitStr = 'pre-store/cvsfds/ekyc_2/ekyc_2/';
let splitMatches = splitStr.split('/');
let splitLink = `${splitMatches[0]}/${splitMatches[1]}/`;
document.write(`<br><br>split method:<br> ${splitLink}`);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I do not think it helps me to solve my problem within google tag manager. I did try and construct ```pre-store\/[\/]*[^\/]+[\/]([^\/]+)\/``` - however it ended up doing the opposite and targeting the ```/cvsfds/ekyc_2/ekyc_2``` strings instead.